# How to push a gem without auth?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, hosted

How can I push gem to a private server without an authorization? Is there a way to disable it?

```
gem push mygem-0.0.0.gem --host http://localhost:51856
Enter your http://localhost:51979 credentials.
Don't have an account yet? Create one at http://localhost:51979/sign_up
```

The private server does not require authorization. The question is how to disable it for the gem push operation?

Comment: What server do you use?

Comment: @spickermann, a server developed by myself

Comment: I am sorry my question was not clear. My understanding of your question is: You are running a private RubyGems server and you need help on how to configure the server. My question is: What server software do you use because there is different software available to run private RubyGems server.

Comment: I wrote own server software

Comment: Did you try to set a random `GEM_HOST_API_KEY` ENV variable? See: https://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#description-18

Comment: @spickermann, that is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

On the one side, you wrote your gem server on your own and your server does not need and therefore does not check credentials. On the other side, the `gem push` command expects that the gem server always requires credentials.

A workaround could be to configure a random [`GEM_HOST_API_KEY`](https://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#description-18) environment variable. When that variable existing, the `gem push` command will not ask for credentials anymore and will instead send that random API key, which then will be ignored by your server.